# Регулярное выражение с оператором OR

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Мне нужно найти с помощью рег. выражения строки, которые удовлетворяют сразу **все** следующие условия:

1. **Обязательно** начинается с символа '#'
2. Далее может следовать последовательность [0-9](но **не обязательно**)
3. Далее **обязательно** следует символ '%' **или** '*' **или** последотовательность [A-Z]
4. Строка **обязательно** заканчивается на '#'

Примеры строк, которые должны совпадать:

```
#1212%#
#1212*#
#*#
#%#
#AVEJE#
#242435AVEJE#
```

Я составил рег. выражение и оно выполняет все условия, кроме одного: оно почему-то совпадает со строкой `##`

Само рег. выражение: `^#[0-9]*([A-Z]*|%|\\*)#$`

В чем состоит ошибка? Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас `[A-Z]*` подразумевает, что может быть 0 и более букв. `##` как раз под этот случай подпадает.

Надо не `*`, а `+` (что подразумевает 1 и более) использовать: `^#[0-9]*([A-Z]+|%|\\*)#$`.

Comment: Вероятно вы мыслили символ `+` (а не `.`).

Comment: Хм, действительно D: Спасибо.